# How do I know if an ethernet cable is compatible w/ router, modem, jack?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, ethernet, compatibility

I don't know how to figure out whether or not components in my internet setup will be compatible if I buy a better ethernet cable than my ISP has provided.

I've got internet service that claims to download "up to" 1,000 Mbps.

The cable installed by my provider has no cat identification on it, but the circumference is small, and I'm sure my provider goes cheap on components.

I would like to buy a cat6 or 6a, but I don't know how to figure out if I've got a compatible jack in the wall -- or if the jack makes a difference, since it's not directly connected to the router.

(Coaxial cable is split between an internet router and the TV gateway) ....

The speed of the signal is determined by the slowest link in the connection (the router, the cable, etc), right?

So how do I make sure all the elements will work together and move the signal as fast as possible?

Comment: Pretty simple, connect whatever cable you have and run a speed test. If you're getting what the ISP is offering as far as speeds, then you're all set.

Comment: “…and I'm sure my provider goes cheap on components.” Why? Where do you get this idea from? This all sounds like you are massively overthinking this. Just plug in the cable, go to a speed test site and check the speed. If it matches what you paid for that’s that.

Comment: *The cable installed by my provider has no cat identification on it, but the circumference is small, and I'm sure my provider goes cheap on components.* *I've got internet service that claims to download "up to" 1,000 Mbps.* The cable is in the provider's area of responsibility. If speedtest (download from some provider's site) shows less download speed whereas your computer may download with 1Gbps (attaching the router to another computer instead of provider's cable) then you can make claims to the provider about non-compliance. PS. "Up to" and "always equal" is not the same.

Comment: PPS. If port connection speed is 1Gbps full duplex and port statistic shows zero errors count then there are no complaints about the cable.

Comment: If the provider was using sub-standard components as a matter of course, then they'd spend half their time having to go back to fix things. Presumably, they would consider the engineer's $50 an hour to be not worth saving $1 on a cable.

Answer (score 0):

Ethernet cables have a rj-45 jack with eight wires.  It is a little bigger but similar to an old 4 wire phone jack.  As long as you get ethernet cable, cat 6 or better, you'll be fine.